# Windows 10 Driver Signing automation

Tags: azure, windows-10, azure-blob-storage, driver-signing

I am using this link as reference:
[DriverSigningAutomation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn800660%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Trying to upload .cab file on sas uri using this code:

```
URI sasUrl = new URI(sasURL);

    try
    {
        CloudBlockBlob blob = new CloudBlockBlob(sasUrl);
        File source = new File(filePath);
        blob.upload(new FileInputStream(source), source.length());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Output the stack trace.
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Few Issues which I am currently facing:

1. How to track the status of uploaded file as on the dashboard ([submissionPortal](https://sysdev.microsoft.com/en-US/Hardware/member/SubmissionCenter)) it says waiting for upload?
2. Is there any way I can get the response stating that file has been uploaded successfully?

Answer (score 0):

Is your uploaded file large? If so, you can try our exe tool [AzCopy](http://aka.ms/azcopy) or its core library [Storage Data Movement Library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement/) (only in C# though). They can achieve container/directory/blob transferring (downloading/uploading/copying) in very high speed and can track the transferring status programmatically. Even pause/resume is supported.

Please note that the SAS provided to the two tools above should be created in container level.

Comment: My sas URI is blob level , is there any other way to get it around?